# Jquery ajax call and mvc controller

Tags: jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

I am performing an ajax call using jquery to my mvc controller.

My requirement is, if some conditions fail, I want to execute error event of ajax call.

How can I achieve it?

Comment: by doing a good research on the topic and then come back with some code - if you don't have the answer

Answer (score 0):

you can add some callback to your AJAX object before sending it, one of them is `error`. You can set your error handling there.

```
$.ajax({
    /*...*/
    success: function(data) {
        // play with your data  ;)
    },
    error: function(error) {
        //show error
        console.error(error.data);
    },
    /*...*/
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use complete callback of jquery [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to handle any response which is executed after success/error callback.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery success and error handing like below

```
$.ajax({
        context: this,
        url: YOUR_URL,
        type: 'POST',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'JSON',
        success: function (data) { 
         // do something
    },
     error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
        console.log(xhr.responseJSON.error);
      }                          

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Jquery's ajax takes in a parameter error, which will be called if the server responds with an error code.

If the server does not throw and error but still fails for some reason you may want to send a flag (isSuccess?), to determine whether or not it succeed. If not run whatever code you want in the success parameter.

Comment: How to return an error code? Your answer is close to answer.

Comment: generally an error code will be sent when the server method throws an uncatched exception.

Comment: But I catched my exception. I want to explicitly send an error code.

Comment: can you show what you return?

you can use 


`return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus)`

a list of httpStauses can be found here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpstatuscode(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: look at my previous comment or you cant simply set return Json(new {done = false}) and in your ajax method check if done is true or false

Comment: You need to set the status code with return data like 200,201,500. if Json with 500 internal server error then it will execute the error event in ajax

Comment: Hey got the solution. Return badrequest